# How can retrieve Facebook friends in a friendlist?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am retrieving the Facebook friends; can you suggest how to retrieve from Facebook from the given code. I am new to android. so please do help me for this. I am not getting proper guideline from Facebook SDK.

The code is as per below.

Friends Application

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.Request;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.HttpMethod;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private LoginButton loginBtn;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private ListView friendList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        friendList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.friends_list);

        loginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
        loginBtn.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
        loginBtn.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_friends"));

//      final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                if (user != null) {
//                  new Request(
//                          Session.getActiveSession(),
//                          "/me/friends",
//                          null,
//                          HttpMethod.GET,
//                          new Request.Callback() {
//                              public void onCompleted(Response response) {
//                                  System.out.println("RESPONSE :- " + response.toString());
//                                  Log.i("DJ", "response; " + response.toString());
//                              }
//                          }).executeAsync();
                } else {

                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook session opened.");
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook session closed.");
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first submit your app at facebook you can find it from the console where you generated your APP id. Because facebook only allow general
    profile info to apps now for more permission assigned to your access token
    you need to create:

1. Release key
2. .apk file
3. A logo 1024*1024
4. fill the app description at facebook apps console.

then with in 3-7 days they will authorize your app to access other permission which you request while submission.

Comment: I have did all the things i have my fb app id and release key too

app id :- 1547076915541502